# Shortcode working in page.php but not in category.php in wordpress

Tags: php, theme-development

I use the latest version of wordpress under php7, I use a theme that uses itself the plugin WPBakery Page Builder (based on visual composer).

I create a post that contains this:

```
[vc_row el_id="bloc-doc-a-telecharger"]
    [vc_column]
        [vc_basic_grid post_type="post" max_items="-1" style="pagination" items_per_page="4" element_width="3" arrows_design="vc_arrow-icon-arrow_09_left" arrows_position="outside" arrows_color="white" paging_color="white" item="1234" taxonomies="123"]
    [/vc_column]
[/vc_row]
```

Shortcode so. Most of the time I can copy this kind of code and integrate it in php with `do_shortcode('[my_short_code'])` but it does not work here, it shows me the message "nothing_found". This is the `style="pagination"` that causes the error.

I specify that I try to integrate it in the file `category.php` and that if I integrate exactly the same code in `page.php` there it works.

Comment: You can add your VC code in a variable then using echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $your_variable); you can get shortcode data.

Comment: OK, just tried but it does the same...

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem, in fact when you add pagination to visual composer post-grid shortcode, it will use ajax to load the things. But to communicate to the ajax php script it uses the post id. 
The problem is that the shortcode will have no post id if you create it live, or another post id if you use an external post as a model.

Then to make it works, I first create a page with the short code I want, then in my other page I get it contents like that :

```
$post = get_posts(array(    'name' => 'my-page-slug','post_type' => 'page'))[0];
print do_shortcode($post->post_content);
```

Notice the `$post` that is a global variable used by visual composer and that now have the correct post ID.

Answer (score -1):

use shortcode inside single quotes as:

```
 do_shortcode('[my_short_code]');
```

Comment: How is that related to the question?

Comment: Yes you're true but that was just an example and I forgot the quotes typing...